# jQuery 1.6.2 Upgrade causing problem with meta selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, metadata, sizzle, facebook-opengraph

This worked fine with 1.4.

```
var ogimagetag = $('meta[property=og:image]').attr('content');
```

gives me

> Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [property=og:image]

The error seems to be sizzle.

```
Sizzle.error = function( msg ) {
    throw "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg;
};
jquery-1.6.2.js:4057 Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [property=og:image]
```

Anyone know how I can select the content of og:image meta without causing an error?  Or is this a bug with sizzle?

Comment: No problem.  Just so you know, use the `{ }` button in the toolbar for code blocks.

Comment: Was first broken in `jQuery 1.5`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put the value in quotes.  I think it's the `:` that's confusing sizzle.  Quoting the value fixes this.

```
var ogimagetag = $('meta[property="og:image"]').attr('content');
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/n7zse/

Comment: +1 this is correct. Attribute values in selector expressions must be surrounded by quotation marks (according to http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)